# Help understanding Deleuzian realism?

Tags: ontology, realism, essence

I am interested in reading a philosophy book titled ["Intensive Science And Virtual Philosophy"](https://www.scribd.com/doc/46673954/DeLanda-M-Intensive-Science-and-Virtual-Philosophy-on-Deleuze-Continuum-2002) by Manuel DeLanda.  It deals with a new field of philosophy called speculative realism.  As I understand it, the meaning of speculative realism is that everything is an object, including sodium atoms, people, colors, and feelings.  Correct me if I am wrong here.

DeLanda adopts the realist ontology of Deleuze, where multiplicities replace essences in creating an ontology of objects. This [concept map](https://jumpshare.com/v/SjJ3es0LVWjGoGfh1maE) shows the contrast. How would one use the concept of multiplicity to explain how people manipulate objects in the universe, like the ones I mentioned above? Would anyone help me understand DeLanda's book in this regard?

Comment: There's a lot of questions here -- maybe zoom in on what is spec realism?

Comment: You can try also with [this book](http://www.re-press.org/book-files/OA_Version_Speculative_Turn_9780980668346.pdf).

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Your question is not of the academic philosophy type that we answer here, [Worldbuilding SE](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com) or [SciFi SE](http://scifi.stackexchange.com) might be better places to ask it. Alternatively, you could ask a different question about the relationship between Deleuzian philosophy and modern science as seen by DeLanda, and ontological advantages of multiplicities vs essences, but leaving out the science fiction part.

Comment: Thank you Mauro for your recommendation.  It does look like a good book.

Comment: There was a useful meta question about this post, why did you remove it?

Comment: Nobody was answering my meta question, and I was fearful that my original question would be deleted, so I thought that as a compromise, I would change the wording of the question to make it palatable to the people who raised objections about it.  My new question that you deleted was similar, but not to same as the question above.  I had reworded it so that it was the same as an earlier question that was acceptable by the editors.  If you like, I can post the meta question again.

Comment: There's not a simple way to respond to all of the questions posed here. The question "How would one use the concept of multiplicity to explain how people manipulate objects in the universe?" presupposes an understanding of multiplicities and in particular how Deleuze treats it in both his treatments of Bergson and Riemann. So there's really two questions, explaining multiplicities in the context of the continuous and discontinuous but also explaining how they relate to non-discursivity (and the continuous and discontinuous from the perspective of non-discursivity).